# Using d3.drag() to enable dragging on an SVG group

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm using the following function to enable dragging on an SVG group.

```
var dragcontainer = d3.drag()
                        .on("start", function () { })
                        .on("drag", function (d, i) {

                            this.x = this.x || 0;
                            this.y = this.y || 0;

                            this.x += d3.event.dx;
                            this.y += d3.event.dy;
                            d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + this.x + "," + this.y + ")");

                        })
                        .on("end", function () {});

d3.select("#svg-group-id").call(dragcontainer);
```

Is there a better (simpler) way to achieve this than manually updating the translate destination?

Comment: Zoom and drag made possible with d3.behavior.zoom: http://jsfiddle.net/9cWWW/6/. Could this work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a simpler way to achieve this: just use `d3.event.x` and `d3.event.y`, holding their values in the bound data.

Thus, your drag function can be reduced to only this:

```
var dragcontainer = d3.drag()
    .on("drag", function(d, i) {
        d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + (d.x = d3.event.x) + ","
        + (d.y = d3.event.y) + ")");
    })
```

And, since you don't use them, just drop your `"start"` and `"end"` listeners.

Here is the demo (click and drag the group around):

```js
var dragcontainer = d3.drag()
  .on("drag", function(d, i) {
    d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + (d.x = d3.event.x) + "," + (d.y = d3.event.y) + ")");
  });
var g = d3.select("g").datum({x: 0, y: 0}).call(dragcontainer)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg style="border: 1px solid gray">
  <g>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="teal"></circle>
    <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="20" fill="tomato"></circle>
    <circle cx="150" cy="50" r="20" fill="tan"></circle>
  </g>
</svg>
```